# Why do I get an "rsync: failed to set times on ... : Operation not permitted (1)" error on Ubuntu 10.10 with SME Server 7.4?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, permissions, rsync, sme-server

I am trying to cron an rsync via ssh between two fileservers that are running SME Server 7.4 and Ubuntu 10.10, respectively. The first rsync worked just fine (for reasons that I do not know), but now, well... here's the output:

```
[i@i-drive ~]$ rsync -avz -e ssh /home/e-smith/files/ibays/drive-i/files/Warehouse\ Pics/* fm-backup@[hostname removed]:~/img_all/
sending incremental file list
Converted Warehouse Pictures/
rsync: failed to set times on "/home/fm-backup/img_all/Converted Warehouse Pictures": Operation not permitted (1)
Converted Warehouse Pictures/12903-13099/
rsync: failed to set times on "/home/fm-backup/img_all/Converted Warehouse Pictures/12903-13099": Operation not permitted (1)
Converted Warehouse Pictures/12903-13099/13038/
rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/home/fm-backup/img_all/Converted Warehouse Pictures/12903-13099/13038" failed: Permission denied (13)
*** Skipping any contents from this failed directory ***
Converted Warehouse Pictures/30500 - 30600/30677/
rsync: failed to set times on "/home/fm-backup/img_all/Converted Warehouse Pictures/30500 - 30600/30677": Operation not permitted (1)
Converted Warehouse Pictures/30500 - 30600/30677/P1430928.JPG
Converted Warehouse Pictures/30500 - 30600/30677/P1430929.JPG
rsync: mkstemp "/home/fm-backup/img_all/Converted Warehouse Pictures/30500 - 30600/30677/.P1430928.JPG.8SDmeO" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: mkstemp "/home/fm-backup/img_all/Converted Warehouse Pictures/30500 - 30600/30677/.P1430929.JPG.qEfwpI" failed: Permission denied (13)
Converted Warehouse Pictures/30900 - 31000/
rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/home/fm-backup/img_all/Converted Warehouse Pictures/30900 - 31000" failed: Permission denied (13)
*** Skipping any contents from this failed directory ***
Converted Warehouse Pictures/Tiff's Folder/
rsync: failed to set times on "/home/fm-backup/img_all/Converted Warehouse Pictures/Tiff's Folder": Operation not permitted (1)
Converted Warehouse Pictures/Tiff's Folder/IMG_3474.JPG
Converted Warehouse Pictures/Tiff's Folder/IMG_3475.JPG
Converted Warehouse Pictures/Tiff's Folder/IMG_3476.JPG
rsync: mkstemp "/home/fm-backup/img_all/Converted Warehouse Pictures/Tiff's Folder/.IMG_3474.JPG.aBPfwH" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: mkstemp "/home/fm-backup/img_all/Converted Warehouse Pictures/Tiff's Folder/.IMG_3475.JPG.4rQNSM" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: mkstemp "/home/fm-backup/img_all/Converted Warehouse Pictures/Tiff's Folder/.IMG_3476.JPG.EpQJkY" failed: Permission denied (13)
Unconverted Warehouse Pictures/PANA 1430200/Thumbs.db
Unconverted Warehouse Pictures/PANA 1430300/
rsync: failed to set times on "/home/fm-backup/img_all/Unconverted Warehouse Pictures/PANA 1430300": Operation not permitted (1)
Unconverted Warehouse Pictures/PANA 1430300/Thumbs.db
Unconverted Warehouse Pictures/PANA 1430400/
rsync: failed to set times on "/home/fm-backup/img_all/Unconverted Warehouse Pictures/PANA 1430400": Operation not permitted (1)
Unconverted Warehouse Pictures/PANA 1430400/Thumbs.db
Unconverted Warehouse Pictures/PANA 1430500/
rsync: failed to set times on "/home/fm-backup/img_all/Unconverted Warehouse Pictures/PANA 1430500": Operation not permitted (1)
Unconverted Warehouse Pictures/PANA 1430500/Thumbs.db
Unconverted Warehouse Pictures/PANA 1430600/
rsync: failed to set times on "/home/fm-backup/img_all/Unconverted Warehouse Pictures/PANA 1430600": Operation not permitted (1)
Unconverted Warehouse Pictures/PANA 1430600/Thumbs.db
Unconverted Warehouse Pictures/PANA 1430700/
rsync: failed to set times on "/home/fm-backup/img_all/Unconverted Warehouse Pictures/PANA 1430700": Operation not permitted (1)
Unconverted Warehouse Pictures/PANA 1430700/Thumbs.db
Unconverted Warehouse Pictures/PANA 1430800/
rsync: failed to set times on "/home/fm-backup/img_all/Unconverted Warehouse Pictures/PANA 1430800": Operation not permitted (1)
Unconverted Warehouse Pictures/PANA 1430800/Thumbs.db
Unconverted Warehouse Pictures/PANA 1430900/
rsync: failed to set times on "/home/fm-backup/img_all/Unconverted Warehouse Pictures/PANA 1430900": Operation not permitted (1)
Unconverted Warehouse Pictures/PANA 1430900/Thumbs.db
Unconverted Warehouse Pictures/PANA 1440000/
rsync: failed to set times on "/home/fm-backup/img_all/Unconverted Warehouse Pictures/PANA 1440000": Operation not permitted (1)
Unconverted Warehouse Pictures/PANA 1440000/Thumbs.db
Unconverted Warehouse Pictures/PANA 1440100/
rsync: failed to set times on "/home/fm-backup/img_all/Unconverted Warehouse Pictures/PANA 1440100": Operation not permitted (1)
Unconverted Warehouse Pictures/PANA 1440100/Thumbs.db
Unconverted Warehouse Pictures/PANA 1440200/
rsync: failed to set times on "/home/fm-backup/img_all/Unconverted Warehouse Pictures/PANA 1440200": Operation not permitted (1)
Unconverted Warehouse Pictures/PANA 1440200/Thumbs.db
rsync: mkstemp "/home/fm-backup/img_all/Unconverted Warehouse Pictures/PANA 1430200/.Thumbs.db.IRLwfB" failed: Permission denied (13)
inflate returned -3 (0 bytes)
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at token.c(546) [receiver=3.0.7]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (8118 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(601) [sender=3.0.7]
```

(Note: Trust me, I know that TRWTF is the terrible and horrible way that the directory is organized. That's another project for another day.)

Neither account is root, and I don't want to have to make the accounts root for this to work.

i@i-drive rsyncs just fine to my OSX fileserver, and from the same folder, even. The account on the OSX box isn't root, either.

Answer (score 9):

I'm pretty sure I got it sorted... I had to `chmod -R 777` the folder on fm-backup, and change the `rsync` options from `...-avz...` to -`...rvz...`. The only thing the Ubuntu box is even used for is to remotely back up files, so I don't see that as a problem.

Comment: in `man rync` say about `-a`: `archive mode; same as -rlptgoD`

Comment: @juanpablo, That was probably the issue. Archive mode sets timestamps, which his user can't.

Comment: I like to use `-a --omit-dir-times` and maybe add `--no-times` if that is also needed.

Answer (score 2):

The user that `cron` runs that `rsync` script with does not own, or has no write permission to, the target directory, and thus can't create files or alter access times.