# rsync: failed to set permissions on "/path/to/file.txt": Operation not permitted (1)

Tags: permissions, rsync

I encountered the error when attempting to transfer source files from a remote Linux web server to a local HP dt1000i Desktop Hard Drive connected to an Ubuntu 12.10 box via USB.

A Samba share is configured for the HP drive to enable the Windows machines on my LAN to access the files. Samba was set up using the built-in graphical folder sharing functionality within Ubuntu. I can modify the files fine in Windows, but problems occur using `rsync`.

When the error occurred, I was trying to use `rsync` to backup files from my web space to the HP drive. I executed the `rsync` command in PuTTY from a Windows 8 machine on my LAN:

`rsync -avz --progress --partial -e 'ssh -p 2222' user@www.example.com:/home/user/ /media/HPDesktopDrive/Backup/HostGator/`

This resulted in the following error: `rsync: failed to set permissions on "/path/to/file.txt": Operation not permitted (1)`.

I thought the source of the error was the mount options for the HP drive in the `/etc/fstab` file: both the `user_id` and `group_id` options were set to zero so I tried change them to `1000` as per the advice in [NAS box mounted via CIFS - problem with permissions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27973/nas-box-mounted-via-cifs-problem-with-permissions).

An `ls -la` of the Samba share reports that the user and group are recursively set to `root:root`. I tried to address this by executing `sudo chown -R mike:mike /media/HPDesktopDrive/`, but the files are still set to `root:root`.

What is the correct command to change the permissions from my Windows machine via PuTTY and will this address the problem?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10044/why-do-i-get-an-rsync-failed-to-set-times-on-operation-not-permitted-1

Answer (score 3):

Chances are, this falls into one of the following:

- There is an ACL that the webhost supports, which the Samba drive does not support.
- You are rsync'ing files from the webhost to the Samba share as a user, which does not have rights to chown files.
- A mounted filesystem will not necessarily allow all permissions/acl/ownership details to be available for change.

As for the Samba share, you may need to setup the share to allow for unique ownership of files, which may mean a need to add additional accounts to HP unit.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For what it's worth, the problem was caused by incorrect syntax in the `/etc/fstab` file: `user_id` and `group_id` as opposed to `uid` and `gid`. The drive is now mounted with `mike:mike` permissions and the problem is resolved.

Comment: Nice. Glad you found the root cause!